# In what scenario is reputation change not traceable through reputation tab?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

Yesterday when I signed off, my header bar was showing reputation something like

[image: Yesterday's Reputation: 14290]

Today, it is showing like

[image: Today's Reputation: 14275]

Yes, I have the "show removed posts" box checked; still, nothing shows up in the reputation tab justifying that drop.

As per the numerical values, it is likely that this may be a part of an accept/unaccept duo, but if so, then why is that break-down (+15/-15) not visible in the reputation tab? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think also if users get deleted who voted on your questions that can also not show, probably not what you are seeing though.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Then what about "user was removed" thing? ndhowever, that would be in (+/- 10) order. :-)

Comment: Are you in the habit of screen-shotting your reputation bar every night before bed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like during the day one of your answers was accepted and then unaccepted, leading to this `-15` in your reputation. This does not leave any trace in your profile, so you have to check the timeline of the question itself.

I went through your answers of yesterday that got upvotes and found two possible cases:

- [comparing and defining strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373011/comparing-and-defining-strings-in-c) (see [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29373011/timeline)).
- [How to resolve "parameter has incomplete type" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371704/how-to-resolve-parameter-has-incomplete-type-error) (see [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29371704/timeline))

Comment: Thank you sir for the response. In that context, I would like to refer to my reputation history for Feb 1st. There it is showing the expected (`+15`/ `-15`) breakdown. What am I missing for yesterday's case, please?

Comment: The timeline from that question from Feb 1st can be seen in http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27821699/timeline There you see that your answer was initally accepted Jan 30st and then re-accepted on Feb 1st. So: you see the breakdown if it happens on different days; if it is within the same, it does not show. Internally, you can see http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation giving you the +15 on the day it was accepted for the last time.

Comment: What the... I have never seen those timelines and fully expected to be denied access. How do you access them? There is no link and I wasn't able to concoct the URL for a random post.

Comment: @musiKk from a "questions" link, change "questions" to "posts" and the title to "timeline". There's probably an easier way....

Comment: @BillWoodger I do it like this and haven't found any workaround to get there. It is a bit long, would be good to have a link directly from the question itself!

Comment: @BillWoodger Whoops, I thought I tried that. Must have used a share URL from an answer which has different IDs. This is fascinating data. Data. Soooo much data...